# Xfc4 Power Manager shuts down when battery is being unplugged

Tags: power-management, xfce, battery

I have Lubuntu 17.10 on my Acer netbook. When I unplug my battery then the system tray icon disappears. Turns out that Xfc4 Power Manager is shutting down when I unplug my battery. And when I plug it back in then it does not come back. I have to go to the Power Manager and the message *"Xfce4 Power Manager is not running, do you want to launch it now?"* appears and after clicking "Run" the system tray icon shows up again.

Could anybody help me on how I get it to run permanently? I would like to have the tray icon even if it does not run on battery.